# establish relation between merge commit on master with squashed and merged PR

Tags: github, github-api

I am currently experimenting with Github API v3 and want to establish a relation between the latest merge commit on master branch with a sqashed, merged and closed PR.

Is it even possible with their APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I query the issues endpoint with the merge commit id to get the PR it is part of (if any)